# How do I examine xhr objects and models from error messages in a backbone save request?

Tags: backbone.js, error-handling, model

Below is an example function of a model being saved, and the error handling involved. I want to put control flow in the error handling so for specific types of errors one thing happens and for another type of error, another thing happens, but I can't seem to examine the xhr with console logs or debugger.

```
propChange: function (newName) {
    var self = this;
    var oldProp = this.model.get('prop');
    this.model.save({ name: newProp }, {
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                ...
            },
            error: function (model, xhr) {
                //I can't console.log anything hear, use debugger, or put a break point here so how do I investigate or experiment with what model and xhr could be at this point?
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: What's the server response code after save?

Comment: *I can't console.log anything hear* - why? What's preventing you from typing `console.log` in there?

Comment: it works now for some reason, I can console log now. But is there no way to use debugger?

Comment: Adding `debugger;` into `error()` should work. Adding a breakpoint does not work since there's no statement the breakpoint could anchor to. Add some dummy staement like `var foo = 1;` to be able to add a breakpoint there.